# TransactionScope locking table and IsolationLevel

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, transactions, transactionscope

I want to use `TransactionScope` in my project. I read about it and I found that it creates an implicit transaction in the database. I want to know if that `TransactionScope` locks tables that it manipulates?

For example in this code:

```
using (Entities ent = new Entities())
{
    using (TransactionScope tran = Common.GetTransactionScope())
    {
        var oldRecords = ent.tblUser.Where(o => o.UserID == UserID);

        foreach (var item in oldRecords)
        {
           ent.tblUser.DeleteObject(item);
        }
```

and

```
public static TransactionScope GetTransactionScope()
{
    TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
    return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
}
```

Is `tblUser` locked until `Complete` command issue?

Does `IsolationLevel` in explicit transaction similar to implicit transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's **SQL Server** that does the locking - if needed. **Any** `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operation must get an **exclusive lock** on those rows it affects - if those are locked already by another transaction, it cannot do that.

So in your case, if you're deleted a number of rows from the database, SQL Server by default will lock **those rows only** - those that are being deleted. It doesn't lock the whole table. This is **unless** you delete a very large number of rows at once - if you delete more then **5'000** rows in a single transaction, SQL Server will try to do a **lock escalation** and lock the whole table (instead of keeping and managing 5000+ individual row locks).

The isolation level only defines how long **reading** will lock a row - by default (`READ COMMITTED`), the row will have a **shared** lock only for the time it's being read - typically a very very short time. With isolation level **REPEATABLE READ**, the shared lock will be held until the end of the current transaction, and **SERIALIZABLE** will not only lock the rows being read, but entire ranges of rows. But again: that **only** affects **READ** operations - it has no direct impact on the `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statements (other than having a shared lock on a row might prevent the `DELETE` from acquiring it's exclusive lock that it needs)

Comment: Nice answer. @marc_s in above code if I delete record with `ID=1` and in that moment another thread want to read `ID=1` what happened? You said that I should get exclusive lock but `TransactionScope`  get implicit lock?

Comment: If your `DELETE` transaction gets the exclusive lock, no other transaction can read this row - it will be locked, and will possibly time out